# How to skip validation of specific constraints?

Tags: grails

Assume I have the following `Foo` object:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(foo: "foo", bar: "bar", baz: "baz")
```

I know how to validation specific constraints:

```
foo.validate(["foo", "bar"]) // validates the "foo" property and the "bar" property, but not the "baz" property
```

I also know how to forego validation all together:

```
foo.save(validate: false)
```

But I don't know how to tell Grails to validate all constraints **except** those in a list.  I could make a method that does what I want, but I wanted to make sure there wasn't a Groovy way to do it first.

**Update**

Here is how I will do this if there isn't a "groovier" way.

```
    // This method exists in my Util.groovy class in my src/groovy folder
    static def validateWithBlacklistAndSave(def obj, def blacklist = null) {
        def propertiesToValidate = obj.domainClass.constraints.keySet().collectMany{ !blacklist?.contains(it)?  [it] : [] }
        if(obj.validate(propertiesToValidate)) {
            obj.save(flush: true, validate: false)
        }
        obj
    }
```

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Considering the below `Foo` domain class

```
class Foo {
    String foo
    String bar
    String baz

    static constraints = {
        foo size: 4..7
        bar size: 4..7
        baz size: 4..7
    }
}
```

Validation for `baz` can be excluded as follows:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(foo: "fool", bar: "bars", baz: "baz")

//Gather all fields
def allFields = foo.class.declaredFields
                         .collectMany{!it.synthetic ? [it.name] : []}
//Gather excluded fields
def excludedFields = ['baz'] //Add other fields if necessary

//All but excluded fields
def allButExcluded = allFields - excludedFields

assert foo.validate(allButExcluded)
assert foo.save(validate: false) //without validate: false, validation kicks in
assert !foo.errors.allErrors
```

There is no direct way to send a list of excluded fields for validation.

Comment: I was actually looking for a "groovier" way to do this, so I'm not sure if this is helpful yet or not. If a "groovier" way does not exist I was expecting to use [getConstrainedProperties()](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/DefaultGrailsDomainClass.html#getConstrainedProperties()), but it looks like your solution is essentially doing the same thing. Unfortunately for me the only field I don't want to validate is transient and is not contained in the `allFields` list from your answer (though `transients` is, but that probably includes all transient fields).

Comment: Additionally, there are a lot of superfluous entries in the `allFields` list in your solution, namely `constraints`, `instanceControllersDomainBindingApi`, `$defaultDatabindingWhiteList`, `instanceDatabindingApi`, `errors`, `id`, `version`, `log`, and `instanceConvertersApi`. I am unclear why all these entries exist, and why the entry `transients` has been substituted for the actual transient fields.

Comment: I updated my question with the method I would be using if something better does not exist.

Comment: I guess there is no better way to do this :(  Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

You can define customized [constraints](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html) maps, which you can then effectively filter from either supporting command classes or `Config.groovy` *via* `exclude` parameter.